# Passing data from Email DE to Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I am trying to pass data from an email to a cloud page.

In the email I tried both the Attribute, Request and Query and am still unsuccessful. Please let me know what I am missing here. Below show the Attribute method. I also tired adding tags in the URL and it still didn't work.

Email URL:

```
<a href="%%= CloudPagesURL(2700)=%%">Click Here</a>
```

Cloud Page:

```
%%[
var @Billing_Contact__c,
@Company__c,
@EmailAddress,
@SubscriberKey


SET @Billing_Contact_Email__c = AttributeValue("Billing_Contact_Email__c")
SET @Company__c = AttributeValue("Company__c")
SET @EmailAddress = AttributeValue("EmailAddress")
SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey")

]%%

%%=v(@Billing_Contact__c)=%%  <br>
%%=v(@Company__c)=%%  <br>
%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%  <br>
%%=v(@SubscriberKey)=%%  <br>
```

I even used [this](http://%3Ca%20href=%22%25%25=%20CloudPagesURL(2700)=%25%25%22%3EClick%20Here%3C/a%3E) example and it did not work me.

Answer (score 8):

You have a space in the url, and you need to include name and value pairs for all parameters that you want to pass from email to a CloudPage:

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'CampaignCode', @CampCode, 'SegmentName', @SegmentName)=%%
```

Then on a CloudPage, use the RequestParameter function to retrieve the valuse.

Documentation:

CloudPagesURL:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm

RequestParameter: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm